# How to query ActiveRecord with GEOJSON for a latitude longitude

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, geojson

We have a rails backend with ActiveRecord model zones
Each zone has a geo_json property of type TEXT (so the compete JSON is stored).
My challenge now is that for a latitude and longitude I need to return all zones for which the lat/lon is withing the GEOJSOn (there are all polygons)
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are mostly using Postgis

Step 1: use Rgeo gem

- in order to insert your spatial data in Rgeo Format instead of text or json. that way you can use all postgis methods like `st_contains`...etc
- ex: `polygon_to_be_inserted_in_db = RGeo::GeoJSON.decode(geo_polygon, json_parser: :json)` whereas geo_polygon here is a polygon in a geojson format
- Rgeo gem: https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo

Step 2: create Rgeo point from lat and lng

- create a point using Rgeo Factroy
- ex: https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo/blob/master/doc/Examples.md#create-a-point-with-coordinates

Step 3: return all zones that contains that point

- ex: `Zone.where('st_contains(geo_polygon::geometry,?)', rgeo_point)`
- geo_polygon: is your db column name
- ::geometry: type casting your column into geometry not geographic as per postgis docs, st_contains takes in a geometric type not geographic type

Comment: I'm not familiar with Postgis, can you tell more about it? Indevelopment I use SQLite instead of postgres is that a problem

Comment: You are dealing with methods that requires operations on geometric shapes (called spatial operations). ex: finding all zones (polygons) that contains a lat,lng.
You cannot do these types of operations in plain sql. So, there's a db extension called postgis that contains all the spatial operations that you will need. you must use it in your case
https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter
@PeterVandePut

Comment: Thanks i'm installing it now. one more question is what data type should i use to store my geojson an example of the data i need to store is here

Comment: {
  "type" : "FeatureCollection",
  "features" : [{"type":"Feature","id":46,"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-75.026229174999969,41.405409048000081],[-75.026270075999946,41.405446094000069],[-75.026277089999951,41.405452447000073],[-75.02717380699994,41.406264625000063],[-75.031582205999939,41.404178290000061],[-75.031617875999984,41.404161407000061],.......... continued

Comment: in the docs here  github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter you will find all data types, for the example you provided the data type of the column should be 'st_polygon'. And as I told you in my answer, you should first build the object with Rgeo, and then insert it in the DB.